# How to convert variadic arguments to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, variadic

For a project of mine, I created a function to run external commands (reduced to what's important for my question):

```
int run_command(char **output, int *retval, const char *command, const char* const args[])
{
    ...
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        ...
        execvp(command, (char * const *)args);
    }
    ...
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
char *output;
int retval;
const char *command = "find";
const char* const args[] = { command, "/tmp", "-type", "f", NULL };
run_command(&output, &retval, command, args);
```

Now, I created a wrapper that uses **variadic arguments** instead of an array of arguments:

```
int run_command2(char **output, int *retval, const char *command, ...)
{
    va_list val;
    const char **args = NULL;
    int argc;
    int result;

    // Determine number of variadic arguments
    va_start(val, command);
    argc = 2; // leading command + trailing NULL
    while (va_arg(val, const char *) != NULL)
        argc++;
    va_end(val);

    // Allocate args, put references to command / variadic arguments + NULL in args
    args = (const char **) malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));
    args[0] = command;
    va_start(val, command);
    int i = 0;
    do {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argument %i: %s\n", i, args[i]);
        i++;
        args[i] = va_arg(val, const char *);
    } while (args[i] != NULL);
    va_end(val);

    // Run command, free args, return result
    result = run_command(output, retval, command, args);
    free(args);
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: note on do-while loop:
For the last element, `fprintf(stderr, "Argument %i: %s\n", i, NULL)` is called, which is valid on GCC and will simply print '(null)'. For other compilers, behavior might be different or undefined. Thanks to @GiovanniCerretani for pointing this out.

The wrapper is called like this:

```
char *output;
int retval;
run_command2(&output, &retval, "find", "/tmp", "-type", "f", NULL);
```

**My question:**

**The wrapper seems to work fine (Linux/x64/GCC 9.2.0), but is this actually a valid way to convert variadic arguments to array? Or does this just work by accident?** The documentation on `va_*` is quite thin, e.g. there's no mention if a string retrieved using `va_arg()` remains valid when `va_arg()` is called again or after calling `va_end()`.

Comment: It shoud be fine, even if the `do/while` seems bugged as you are printing a `NULL` pointer with `%s`.

Comment: It seems the code shown missed to set the sentinel `NULL`, that is set `args`'s last element to `NULL`.

Comment: @alk the do-while-loop makes sure `args`'s last element is NULL

Comment: No need to malloc/free the argument list (args). You can use variable length array (VLA), after counting the number of arguments: `char *args[argc[ ; argv[0] = command ; ...`

Comment: @dash-o: thanks, didn't known about VLAs. But it would seem Linus Torvalds does not approve ;) https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/7/621

Comment: @Maxxim: Note that Linus's objections are specific to kernel code, which has much more severe restrictions on stack usage.

Comment: @NateEldredge: that was originally meant as a joke, but I think it's worth mentioning that VLAs are controversial. Linus and other critics have valid points, in my opinion.

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani: on GCC printf("%s", NULL) is actually valid and prints '(null)', but in general you are right, with other compilers this will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: `va_arg` cannot possibly retrieve a string. It can retrieve a *pointer* that may point to a string (which is a null-terminated array of characters) stored somewhere.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: That much is obvious. The question was (still is) if the 'null-terminated array of characters that is stored somewhere' is still valid when `va_arg` is used again and/or after `va_end`. In other words: how do the `va_*` macros handle this, are there buffers involved that might get invalidated at some point? Where is that 'somewhere' and how is it handled/organized? The documentation lacks that kind of information. The only way do come up with a definitive answer might actually be to investigate compiler sources.

Comment: "Where is that 'somewhere' and how is it handled/organized?" You called the function, what kind of `char*` arguments did you pass to it? Right, those are pointers to buffers that **you** allocated, handled and organized. Why would any call machinery do anything at all with these buffers? Your buffers are not the arguments to the va_ macros. The pointers are. The macros cannot possibly do anything with these pointers except copying them around. They don't have any information about the size or validity of the buffers, so modifying them would require a clairvoyant compiler.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing will work as expected.

The calls to `va_arg` get you access to the `char *` arguments that were passed to the function.  The values of these pointers is what was passed to `run_command2` meaning their scope is valid at least in the calling function.

So they are valid even after calling `va_end`.

Answer (score 1):

As there's not much available on this topic, I decided to implement all possible wrapper variants I could think of and put them in a Gist: [Link](https://gist.github.com/fonic/a01a7a45e09289635cf19d7878e85103)

Hopefully this helps others facing the same task.

Answer (score -2):

This `args = (const char **) malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));` is quite strange. I would rather first allocate `char **args = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc));` and then `args[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(val) + 1));`

You need to allocate the `char **` and then allocate each string in this array.

Comment: I currently don't copy the strings, I only use references. Thus, `args` is simply an array of references.

Comment: Oh i just figured it out. So it looks good, and you can call var_arg after a va_end, it's valid and working.